# node.js Azure Web App returns 400 on long urls

Tags: node.js, azure, http, kestrel-http-server

I'm hosting a node.js application in an Azure Web App. This works well, except the server always returns HTTP 400 if the request is too long (ie. a long URL or many headers.)

It seems that the error is returned by the Kestrel gateway without reaching my application, and this happens if the length of the request exceeds 2581 bytes in length. The same problem does not occur when running locally. This is a GET request, and it does not make a difference whether the URL is long, or there are long headers.

My application simply returns the current time:

```js
// Module dependencies
let http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log('request ', request.url);

    response.write("Request served at " + new Date().toISOString());
    response.end();
}).listen(80);
```

If I request `GET /anything` the response is as expected. However if I do `GET /{any_very_long_path}` (or include a header with a long value) it fails.

Why would Azure be limiting the request length like this? The same issue does not happen when hosting an ASP.NET application.

Comment: In kestrel, there is no such thing like max url length, but perhaps that you have changed `Kersel MaxRequestLineSize` and you are not aware of it (normally the maximum length is 8kb) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.kestrelserverlimits.maxrequestlinesize?view=aspnetcore-1.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Server_Kestrel_KestrelServerLimits_MaxRequestLineSize. Also there also some data lacking in you question, like what the url you use or the request you send to the server?

Comment: I haven't changed that setting, but unfortunately the server is supplied and configured by Azure without me being able to configure it. I'll update the question to describe how to trigger the issue.

Comment: GET urls should not be kept too long. There is no standard limit to the length but there are some limits in browsers also https://technomanor.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/maximum-url-size/

Comment: @TarunLalwani agreed, but the reason for the long request is the URL parameters and cookies set by Azure AD. And those are beyond my control, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I request `GET` `/anything` the response is as expected.
>
> However if I do `GET` `/{any_very_long_path}` (**or include a header with a long value**)
>   it fails.

I believe the problem is related to [this issue @ GitHub](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/24731),
it mentions :

> On our website, we have pretty big cookies in some scenarios (it might
>   not be good indeed) and we have been facing many **400** http errors since
>   yesterday.

This is because there is a `8KB` hard-coded (`HTTP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE`) limit, anything bigger returns error code `400`...

[Nodejs Documentation : http.maxHeaderSize](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_maxheadersize)

> Read-only property specifying the maximum allowed size of HTTP headers
>   in bytes. Defaults to 8KB. Configurable using the
>   `--max-http-header-size` CLI option.

## Solution :

You could try using the `--max-http-header-size` CLI option as the Docs mention.

Remember that if you are using a reverse proxy in-between (such as NGINX) you will also have to increase the max header size...

Comment: This turned out to be the issue. Thanks for your help.